# apply function not working as expected in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
ID    |     timestamp    |Phase| current
========================================
001   | 2020-09-20 07:00 | A   | 1.4
001   | 2020-09-20 07:00 | B   | 2.0
001   | 2020-09-20 07:00 | C   | 1.6
002   | 2020-09-20 09:00 | A   | 1.4
002   | 2020-09-20 09:00 | B   | 1.23
002   | 2020-09-20 09:00 | C   | 1.46
```

I need to calculate the % difference in the phases of each ID/timestamp grouping, so I create a groupby:

```
imbalanced = df.groupby(['timestamp','ID']).apply(calcImbalance)
```

and here is calcImbalance:

```
def calcImbalance(pole):
    
        phA = pole.loc[pole['Phase'] == 'A']['current'].astype('float')
        phB = pole.loc[pole['Phase'] == 'B']['current'].astype('float')
        phC = pole.loc[pole['Phase'] == 'C']['current'].astype('float')
        
        imb = abs((phA-phB)/phB)
        print ('imb:', imb)
        if imb  >= 0.3:
            return pole
        imb = abs((phB-phA)/phA)
        if imb >= 0.3:
            return pole
        imb = abs((phA-phC)/phC)
        if imb >= 0.3:
            return pole
        imb = abs((phC-phA)/phA)
        if imb >= 0.3:
            return pole
```

But this just prints:

```
imb: 2661   NaN
2662   NaN
Name: Amps, dtype: float64
imb: 2661   NaN
2662   NaN
Name: Amps, dtype: float64
```

and then
throws an exception:
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

What I'm trying to do is create a dataframe of only the instances in df that have a > 30% difference between phases. I think I have gone down a rabbit hole for something that seems like it should be trivial

In the above example, the 'imbalanced' dataframe should contain:

```
ID    |     timestamp    |Phase| current
========================================
001   | 2020-09-20 07:00 | A   | 1.4
001   | 2020-09-20 07:00 | B   | 2.0
```

The apply function doesn't test the imbalance between phases B & C, only A & B and A & C

Comment: Please show an example of what the expected result would be, based on the sample data shown.

Comment: Also, `imb` is a `pandas.Series`, not a single value. When you make a comparison, `imb > 0.3` it needs to know if you mean any of the values, or all of the value in the series. In the case of the sample, `imb` is empty, so the sample isn't helpful.

Comment: Which row has a change > .3 between phases? I can't find any IIUC.

Comment: Sorry, my sample data is bad, there are no instances where the imbalance is >= 30%!

Comment: OK, edited example. ID 001 phase A&B are 42% different.: abs((1.4-2)/1.4)=.42, so it (ID 001 should be contained in the imbalanced dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can find the desired rows with pandas functions

```
df['cng'] = (df.groupby('ID')['current'].pct_change() + 1).groupby(df.ID).cumprod()-1
df[df.groupby('ID')['cng'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.max())) > .30]
```

Output

```
   ID         timestamp Phase  current       cng
0   1  2020-09-20 07:00     A      1.4       NaN
1   1  2020-09-20 07:00     B      2.0  0.428571
```

---

### How this works

To find groups with changes between phases > .30

```
df[df.groupby('ID')['current'].pct_change().groupby(df.ID).transform('max') > .30]
```

Output

```
   ID         timestamp Phase  current
0   1  2020-09-20 07:00     A      1.4
1   1  2020-09-20 07:00     B      2.0
2   1  2020-09-20 07:00     C      1.6
```

This gives the percent change in groups

```
df.groupby('ID')['current'].pct_change()
```

Output

```
0         NaN
1    0.428571
2   -0.200000
3         NaN
4   -0.121429
5    0.186992
```

The accumulated changes per group

```
(df.groupby('ID')['current'].pct_change() + 1).groupby(df.ID).cumprod()
```

Output

```
0         NaN
1    1.428571
2    1.142857
3         NaN
4    0.878571
5    1.042857
```

---

### What can this solution detect?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([('001', '2020-09-20 07:00', 'A', 1.4),
                   ('001', '2020-09-20 07:00', 'B', 2.0),
                   ('001', '2020-09-20 07:00', 'C', 1.6),
                   ('002', '2020-09-20 09:00', 'A', 1.4),
                   ('002', '2020-09-20 09:00', 'B', 1.2),
                   ('002', '2020-09-20 09:00', 'C', 2.0),
                   ('003', '2020-09-20 09:00', 'A', 1.4),
                   ('003', '2020-09-20 09:00', 'B', 2.0),
                   ('003', '2020-09-20 09:00', 'C', 1.6),
                   ('003', '2020-09-20 09:00', 'D', 2.0),

                  ],
                  columns=['ID', 'timestamp', 'Phase', 'current'])
```

In dataframe

```
    ID         timestamp Phase  current  
0  001  2020-09-20 07:00     A      1.4  
1  001  2020-09-20 07:00     B      2.0 
2  001  2020-09-20 07:00     C      1.6 
3  002  2020-09-20 09:00     A      1.4 
4  002  2020-09-20 09:00     B      1.2 
5  002  2020-09-20 09:00     C      2.0 
6  003  2020-09-20 09:00     A      1.4 
7  003  2020-09-20 09:00     B      2.0 
8  003  2020-09-20 09:00     C      1.6 
9  003  2020-09-20 09:00     D      2.0
```

With this solution

```
df['cng'] = (df.groupby('ID')['current'].pct_change() + 1).groupby(df.ID).cumprod()-1
df[df.groupby('ID')['cng'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.max())) > .30]
```

Result. Note that `cng` is the cumulative product to compute the change to the first row.

```
    ID         timestamp Phase  current       cng
0  001  2020-09-20 07:00     A      1.4       NaN
1  001  2020-09-20 07:00     B      2.0  0.428571
3  002  2020-09-20 09:00     A      1.4       NaN
5  002  2020-09-20 09:00     C      2.0  0.428571
6  003  2020-09-20 09:00     A      1.4       NaN
7  003  2020-09-20 09:00     B      2.0  0.428571
9  003  2020-09-20 09:00     D      2.0  0.428571
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for some reason the second line of your answer throws an exception: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4261 elements, new values have 4590 elements`

Comment: With the dataframe you provided in your question?

Comment: Also, the dataframe IS 4590 rows long, so I don't know why the second operation expects only 4261, unless that happens to be the exact number of cng = NaNs

Comment: No, with the actual Dataframe I'm operating on. It's 4590 x 13

Comment: My solution doesn't work with missing values (`NaN`) in the grouping column `ID`. I think you can drop those rows, because you can't  assign them to a group.

Comment: OK, I cleaned up my data a bit so this now works, but it's using a cumulative total of 30%, how can I do it if either of two phases are > 30% imbalanced, not the cumulative imbalance, so either A-B or A-C are > 30% different. They CAN be both > 30%, but only one can and still meet the reqs

Comment: That's what this solution does if I understand you correctly. Its testing if any of the `phase` value is greater than +30% of the first phase. This will also work with more than three phases. I added an example with more cases to clarify what you can detect.

Comment: re-reading the docs, pct_change only compares a value to the previous value, so it would only ever compare a-b and b-c, never a-c. I propose this as a one line solution: `di = df.groupby(['id','timestamp']).filter(lambda x: (x['current'].max()-x['current'].min())/((x['current'].max()+x['current'].min())/2)>=.3)`

Comment: my above solution only looks at min and max current of the group, as if they aren't > .30, then min/median wont be, and if min/max > .30, it doesn't matter

Comment: You missed the `.groupby(df.ID).cumprod()-1`in my solution. But I'm happy that you found a solution by yourself.

Comment: You are right, i admit i don't understad how .cumprod serves to compare a-c in a series. also, I discovered that there's a subtle difference in change vs difference. change is `new-old/old`, difference is `(larger-smaller)/((larger+smaller)/2)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, this may work. This collects the currents into a list and passes them to the `calcImbalance` function.

```
import pandas as pd

dd = {
'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2],
'timestamp':['2020-09-20 07:00','2020-09-20 07:00','2020-09-20 07:00','2020-09-20 09:00','2020-09-20 09:00','2020-09-20 09:00'],
'Phase':['A','B','C','A','B','C'],
'current':[1.4,1.5,1.6,1.4,1.23,1.46]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dd)


def calcImbalance(pole):
        
        phA, phB, phC = tuple(pole)  # currents in group
        print('ph >',phA, phB, phC)
        
        imb = abs((phA-phB)/phB)
        print ('imb:', imb)
        if imb >= 0.3:
            return pole
        imb = abs((phB-phA)/phA)
        if imb >= 0.3:
            return pole
        imb = abs((phA-phC)/phC)
        if imb >= 0.3:
            return pole
        imb = abs((phC-phA)/phA)
        if imb >= 0.3:
            return pole
            

gb = df.groupby(['timestamp','ID'])['current'].apply(lambda x:[i for i in x]).apply(calcImbalance) 

print('\n',gb)
```

Output

```
ph > 1.4 1.5 1.6
imb: 0.06666666666666672
ph > 1.4 1.23 1.46
imb: 0.13821138211382109

timestamp         ID
2020-09-20 07:00  1     None
2020-09-20 09:00  2     None
Name: current, dtype: object
```

-- Update --

Based on your post update, this may not be the full answer but may still help getting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this code answers the question, including the edits.

```
import pandas as pd


def calc_imbalance(current):
    pairs_to_test = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2]]
    for pair in pairs_to_test:
        abs_percentage_imbalance = abs((current[pair[0]] - current[pair[1]])/current[pair[1]])
        if abs_percentage_imbalance >= .3:
            return pair
    return []

df = pd.DataFrame([('001', '2020-09-20 07:00', 'A', 1.4),
                   ('001', '2020-09-20 07:00', 'B', 2.0),
                   ('001', '2020-09-20 07:00', 'C', 1.6),
                   ('002', '2020-09-20 09:00', 'A', 1.4),
                   ('002', '2020-09-20 09:00', 'B', 1.23),
                   ('002', '2020-09-20 09:00', 'C', 1.46)],
                  columns=['ID', 'timestamp', 'Phase', 'current'])

df['original_index'] = df.index

all_index_to_keep = []
for _, group in df.groupby(['timestamp', 'ID']).agg(list).reset_index().iterrows():
    index_to_keep = calc_imbalance(group['current'])
    all_index_to_keep += [v for k, v in enumerate(group['original_index']) if k in index_to_keep]
df.drop('original_index', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df.loc[all_index_to_keep, :])
```

Returns:

```
    ID         timestamp Phase  current
0  001  2020-09-20 07:00     A      1.4
1  001  2020-09-20 07:00     B      2.0
```